# Excel - multiple arguments based on SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a formula that is

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Fct_202109082514!A:A,{"S100GC-I2C","S100GC-I2C-P","S100GC-I2C-O"},Fct_202109082514!E:E))
```

And this works, but it's vulnerable to user error while entering the criteria between the quotation marks
I am trying to summarize a sheet with a lot of data, and let’s just say that I cannot use Pivot Tables for different reasons.

Anyway, I know I can use this formula to reference a cell for the criteria (instead of typing it “S100GC-I2C”); however, I can only enter one criteria like so:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Fct_202109082514!A:A,Table2[@Item],Fct_202109082514!E:E))
```

Is there a way to have multiple criteria? In essence, I am looking for a formula similar to this, which of course it doesn’t work, but I can't wrap my head around it and how to make it work

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Fct_202109082514!A:A,Table2[@Item], Table2[@Item]-P, Table2[@Item]-O,Fct_202109082514!E:E))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the syntactically correct version of your attempt:

`=SUM(SUMIF(Fct_202109082514!A:A,[@Item]&{"","-P","-O"},Fct_202109082514!E:E))`

Comment: Thank you... This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B4:B6=Table3[Column1])*C4:C6)`

Where column B is your criteria list, column C is item quantity and Table3[Column1] is your data list.